# JFXButton Rippler Fill Color Can't Be Change

Tags: java, javafx, styles, jfoenix

I have a problem with styling `JFXButton` from this library : `jfoenix.com`

I would like to change the `JFXButton` Rippler Fill Color, when user click a button. But  it's not working. I checked on the internet. But a solution could not be found. Have you to any ideas?

```
@FXML
private void settingApplyBtnAction(ActionEvent event) {

 //option 1
 paymentBtn.setStyle("-jfx-rippler-fill: " + themeColor);
 //option 2
 paymentBtn.setStyle("-fx-rippler-fill: " + themeColor);

 /*other code....*/

}
```

But if I give a color from SceneBuilder, it's working fine. Anyone can help me.

Comment: Do you want to change your Rippler color from the java code and you want to see the result in scene builder when you add a target method to your method ,or it does not give you any effects in runtime. ?

Comment: I think you'd be better off using css to control your theme. The `JFXRippler` on a button is probably on a `StackPane` or some other node type inside the `JFXButton`. Use the `.jfx-rippler` class to specify the `-jfx-rippler-fill` property. You can use a separate css file for each theme.

Comment: Menai Ala Eddine & RonSiven. Thank you both for your time sharing with me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you must use code to change your theme, try using the `setRipplerFill` method on the JFXButton class.

```
@FXML
private void settingApplyBtnAction(ActionEvent event) {

    paymentBtn.setRipplerFill(Color.valueOf(themeColor));

    /*other code....*/

}
```

Comment: Mr.RonSiven  Thank You So Much.... That's what I really expected. Unfortunately, I do not have the enough reputation to give a vote. But I recommend this answer to every user. Thanks again Mr.RonSiven.

Comment: You're welcome. You should be allowed to mark this as the accepted answer, though. Just click the check mark. :)